# Reference to Controllers which were instantiated through XML

Tags: android, cyborg

I've created an utility controller and instantiated it through the xml (`CyborgView`). So far so good.
I got stuck, however, when I wanted to use it... How do I get a reference of that controller from the xml?
Note that my goal here is to use multiple controllers of the same type.

Comment: What is a utility controller? and did you try to use the getControllerById API?

Comment: It's a control that I want to use multiple times in the same layout. Where do I get the controller id from?

Comment: Its not a controller id, its the **view id** of the CyborgView in your xml, that refers to the controller you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cyborg 0.8.11(available soon) you can use the ViewIdentifier annotation to inject controllers and not only views.

In Cyborg 0.8.10 and below:
You can get controllers in a pretty similar way to getting views, you give the CyborgView an id just like you'd give a view, and then get the controller using that id:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                  xmlns:cyborg="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                  android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.nu.art.cyborg.core.CyborgView
                            android:id="@+id/CV_MyController"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            cyborg:controller="com.me.myself.i.MyController"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in the controller itself, override the extractMembers() function and inside it get the controller:

```
    private MyController myController;

    @Override
    protected void extractMembers() {
         myController = getControllerById(R.id.CV_MyController);
    }
```

To use multiple instances of the same controller, you can differ between them with the id attribute.